# Тег <? воспринимается как <!--?

Tags: php, wordpress, linux-mint

Вот код

```
<p><? echo $adres_header ?></p>
```

В инспекторе он отображается вот так

```
<!--? echo $adres_header ?-->
```

И поэтому в браузере ничего не отображается.

Если писать вот так

```
<?php echo $adres_header ?>
```

То все работает.

Как исправить эту ошибку? Работаю в Linux Mint. Использую LAMP.

Comment: Используйте только `<?php ?>` и `<?= ?>`

Comment: Потому что так прописано у вас в настройках [PHP интерпретатора](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В php.ini нужно включить опцию "short_open_tag"

Comment: Надо не эту фигню включать, а код писать правильно. Как выше в коменнтах говорили.

Comment: Эта опция выключена на большинстве серверов, и включить её на шареде невозможно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну справедливости ради на многих шаредах можно. У многих есть даже возможность править свой персональный  php.ini (с ограниченным набором возможностей, но достаточно много разрешено).